# Postgres nested loop order

Tags: postgresql, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t1.c1 FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.c2 = 'X' AND t1.id = t2.id AND t2.c3 = 'Y';
```

Postgres produces two plans for this query, something like:

```
Nested Loop (rows=1 width=7) (actual rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Index Scan using idx1 on t1 (rows=1 width=7) (actual rows=4 loops=1)
    -> Index Scan using idx2 on t2 (rows=1 width=7) (actual rows=0 loops=7)
```

or:

```
Nested Loop (rows=1 width=7) (actual rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Index Scan using idx2 on t2 (rows=4 width=7) (actual rows=1000000 loops=1)
    -> Index Scan using idx1 on t1 (rows=1 width=7) (actual rows=0 loops=1000000)
```

So, sometimes t1 is chosen for the outer loop, sometimes t2. And if the second plan is chosen performance is absolutely awful.

My question is, how can I force Postgres to always use the first query plan, with t1 in the outer loop?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are running `ANALYZE` on a regular basis. The estimates are way off.

BTW, Postgres will *probably* not care but you *might* get better results with

```
SELECT T1.c1 FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t1.c2='X' AND t2.c3='Y';
```

Comment: ANALYZE is ran on regular basis, there's probably some more tuning I can do on that side, but I was wondering if there's anyway I can force the nested loop order because I'm not sure ANALYZE will solve the problem. I tried using JOIN but got the same results.

Comment: Unless you have simplified the situation too much, ANALYZE hasn't been run in this example. The estimated number of rows for t2 is off by a factor of 250,000. Or the distribution of c2 and c3 is very skewed. You could try rewriting this with a semi-join `t1 NATURAL JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.c3='Y') AS t3 WHERE` etc. but note that if the distribution of c2 and c3 were reversed, you would want the second plan and not the first plan!

Comment: The example is indeed simplified. I will try the semi-join.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use a left join? That should force the join order and return the same result because of the clause on t2.c3:

```
SELECT t1.c1
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.c2 = 'X' AND t2.c3 = 'Y';
```